# getting parameter from a response curl php

Tags: php, curl

I'm really newbie with php. I'm trying to develop a simple php app. 
I have a button in my app and I want when I click on it to open some webpage, allow an user to connect using his credential. When the user is connected he can grant me a privilege to access to his information by clicking in some button "Allow". After clicking in that button, he is redirected to an url that contain a parameter named "code". My goal is to use this code parameter in my php script. 
I found some information about curl and I guess I need it to do that but how ?
I can open google webpage by doing this :

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $result;
?>
```

To resume I would like to know :
1) After redirecting the user to a website, after his logging and allowing me to access to his data, how can I get a parameter that is include to the url he is redirected after allowing me the access. 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the URL parametrs by GET, example

`www.example.com/user?id=1111&Fname=john&Lname=Doe`

...in your PHP : ...

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$Fname=$_GET['Fname'];
$Lname=$_GET['Lname'];
```

To use the CURL :

```
<?php
$url="yourURL?id=$id&Fname=$Fname&Lname=$Lname";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print $result;
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. After redirecting the user for example to http://openam.test.com:8080/openam, so he will do 2 actions (logging and click on some button "Allow") and I only need to retrieve the redirection url he got after clicking on "Allow". How can I get this url in my php script ? I mean the url where I have the parameter I need.

Comment: you are welcome @aicha, to get the url you just need to call $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 at your PHP file, If you want to support both HTTP and HTTPS, you can use

$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

Comment: Ok thank you @Mohamed I'll try it and let you know if it works. I've some issue with my VM right now.